# Extract data from a pandas series if the values are in a dictionary-like format

Tags: python, pandas

I try the solution in [Extracting dictionary values from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927936/extracting-dictionary-values-from-a-pandas-dataframe) But it didn't work.

I have a pandas.core.series.Series with the following general format:

```
0      {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions...
1      {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions...
2      {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions...
3      {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions...
...
```

the specific format of each one is similar to the following:

```
{'hashtags': [],
'symbols': [],
'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'jose_m',
'id_str': '132',
'name': 'Jose',
'indices': [0, 10],
'id': 103},
{'screen_name': 'paul',
 'id_str': '243403',
 'name': 'Jorge',
 'indices': [50, 64],
 'id': 2423}],
 'urls': []}
```

I get that by placing the index zero to the variable `entities[0]` (Index may change).

I need to extract extract all the **screen_name** and **name** inside user_mentions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), for each `entities` returns a list with a tuple for each `user_mention`:

```
def find_user_mention(user_mention):
    return (user_mention['screen_name'], user_mention['name'])

df['entities'].apply(lambda x: [find_user_mention(user_mention) for user_mention in x['user_mentions']])
```

Example output with random data:

```
0                       [(NunkMasKKs,  SUSHIPLANERO )]
1                          [(leobilanski, Leo Bilanski)]
2                      [(romerodiario, El Profe Romero)]
3                              [(HugoYasky, Hugo Yasky)]
4                    [(marianorecalde, Mariano Recalde)]
5                     [(cyngarciaradio, Cynthia García)]
```